# INSERT em duas tabelas diferentes - MySql

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho duas tabelas no Mysql:

- `Alunos: id, nome, idade, email, senha.`
- `login: id, email, senha.`

Quando eu fizer o insert para gravar as informações na tabela `alunos` posso fazer outro insert para gravar o email e senha na `login`?

Comment: Essa resposta pode te ajudar: [Insert MySQLi da forma certa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/220396/problemas-com-inser%c3%a7%c3%a3o-insert-mysql/220402#220402)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provavelmente não tenha deixado tão claro, mas resolvi da seguinte forma:

Recebo os dados de um formulário:

```
$nome = $_POST['nome'];

$idade = $_POST['idade'];

$email = $_POST['email'];

$senha = $_POST['senha'];

$sql1 = "INSERT INTO aluno (nome, idade, email, senha) values ('$nome', '$idade', '$email', '$senha')";

$sql2 = "INSERT INTO login (email, senha) values ('$email', '$senha')";

mysqli_query($conexao, sql1) or die ("Erro"); 

mysqli_query($conexao, sql2) or die ("Erro");

echo 'Gravado com sucesso';
```

Assim gravou nas duas tabelas os dados recebidos do form. :)

Comment: So uma sugestão, mude o `die("erro");` por `die(mysqli_error($conexao));` assim vc sabe qual o aconteceu, facilita para descobrir como resolver ele.

Comment: Obrigado @rray. Fiz a alteração aqui.

Answer (score 6):

Sim, basta criar uma STORED PROCEDURE para fazer a inserção nas duas tabelas;

O código abaixo cria a PROCEDURE:

```
DELIMITER $$ 

    CREATE PROCEDURE Insere(IN aNome VARCHAR(30), IN aIdade INT, IN aEmail VARCHAR(30), IN aSenha VARCHAR(30)) 
    BEGIN 
        INSERT INTO Alunos ( nome, idade, email, senha) VALUES (aNome, aIdade, aEmail, aSenha);
        INSERT INTO Login ( email, senha) VALUES (aEmail, aSenha);
    END $$ 
DELIMITER ;
```

Depois disso é só executar a PROCEDURE com o comando `CALL Insere`

Ex.:

```
CALL Insere ('Fulano', 22, 'fulano@gmail.com', 'senha');
```

Depois disso o usuário será inserido nas duas tabelas.

Comment: Preciso ter chave estrangeira nas tabelas?

Comment: Não precisa, mas é bom ter pra manter a consistência do seu BD.

A procedure que postei fiz usando o seu modelo de banco, mas seria bom você alterar para adicionar a chave estrangeira da tabela de Login para Alunos.

Comment: Tá beleza, vou tentar aqui. Achava que só era um fazer dois comandos de INSERT seguidos e tava de boa xD

Comment: Você pode só rodar os dois comandos INSERT sem problemas. Mas a utilização da PROCEDURE diminui as chances de algum problema ocorrer entre os dois comandos, e o BD ficar inconsistente.

Porém o ideal mesmo nesse caso é utilizar TRANSACTION.

Comment: Esse código posso aplicar direto no PHP? Porque recebo as informações de um formulário

Comment: O código para a criação da PROCEDURE você vai executar uma única vez, pode ser através de um script PHP específico, ou através do cliente que você estiver utilizando, PhpMyAdmin, MySqlAdmin etc ...

No script PHP de cadastro, você só vai fazer a chamada, ou seja, a parte do `CALL Insere ('Fulano', 22, 'fulano@gmail.com', 'senha');`