# Problemas com inserção INSERT mysql

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados

Estou tentando inserir dados em meu banco de dados mysql mas os valores não aparecem na tabela

```
TABELA "users":
id `int`,`11`, `notnull`,`primarykey`,`auto increment`
email `varchar`,`11`, `notnull`
senha `varchar`,`11`, `notnull`
```

---

```
<?php
$email = 'example@mail.com';
$senha = '12345';

$query = 'INSERT INTO users (email,senha) VALUES ('.$email.','.$senha.')';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
?>
```

Comment: Tem uma coisa que identifiquei, você está declarando um valor de até 11 caracteres em sua coluna e-mail `email varchar,11, notnull` e no seu exemplo logo abaixo a _string_ `$email` tem mais de 11 caracteres, provavelmente esse pode ser um erro, outra observação que faço é como está sua conexão?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não comentou a respeito de fez a configuração para se trabalhar com PDO. Pois antes de tudo, é necessário habilitar o driver do PDO e o driver referente ao banco que será utilizado.

Neste [link](http://www.devmedia.com.br/introducao-ao-php-pdo/24973) há um tutorial de como realizar isso.

Logo após você deve iniciar a conexão ao banco:

```
$con = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=nome_banco", "root", "senha");
```

E depois inserir os dados no banco:

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO users (email,senha) VALUES ('.$email.','.$senha.')';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
```

Acrescentando uma observação ou alerta ao seu código. É a falta de tratativas de erros. Caso esteja usando. Parabéns. É para o seu próprio bem. Caso não esteja, seria interessante começar a usar, por exemplo:

Procure certificar-se que sua conexão ocorreu com sucesso. Use o bloco `try{}catch(){}`:

```
$try {
    con = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=nome_banco", "root", "senha");
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $query = 'INSERT INTO users (email,senha) VALUES ('.$email.','.$senha.')';
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Além disso, para tratamento de erros de conexão, foi adicionado a linha `$conn->setAttribute()`. O erro padrão do PDO é o `PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT`. Troque para `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` para ativar a exibição dos erros. Abaixo vou listar as opções que terá:

- *PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT*
- *PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING*
- *PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION*

Após validar essas informações, tente rodar seu `INSERT`. Caso de erro, atualize sua pergunta com o erro para que possamos te ajudar melhor.