# Insert banco mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Ola!

O primeiro código php gera vários inputs. Onde o usuário informa quantos inputs ele deseja na variável $valor.

```
for ($i=1; $i <=$valor ; $i++) { 

                echo "
                <label>Chamado $i:</label><br>
                <input type='number' name='valor %i' placeholder='Chamado'>
                <br><br>
                ";

              }
```

so que gostaria de saber como fazer o insert baseado na quantidade que o usuário digitou?

Comment: Tente colocar mais detalhes do seu código, para que você possa receber uma ajuda de qualidade.

Comment: Essa resposta pode te ajudar: [Insert MySQLi da forma certa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/220396/problemas-com-inser%c3%a7%c3%a3o-insert-mysql/220402#220402)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você vai receber a variavel `$valor` do front-end ou afins onde o usuário irá informar o valor e dar um submit, você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
$valor = sizeof($_POST['valor']); // ou $_GET ( caso tenha que percorrer a quantidade de elementos).

ou

$valor = $_POST['valor']; // ou $_GET (caso só tenha que receber o valor digitado pelo usuário em um input)

for ($i = 0; $i < $valor; $i) {
   $valor1 = $_POST['nome'][$i];
   $valor2 = $_POST['telefone'][$i];

   $query = "INSERT INTO database VALUES ('$valor1' , '$valor2')";
}
```

Fiz um exemplo pra você criando algumas variaveis, pois não sei o que você está enviando para seu script / banco, então no caso você colocaria a suas ali no lugar. Em resumo você verifica a quantidade do valor pegando o `sizeof` da váriavel caso ele tenha que percorrer a quantidade existente, ou apenas você recebe ela como no segundo parâmetro via `$_POST` de acordo com o que o usuário digitar.

Answer (score 0):

Provavelmente ele irá preencher a variável em outro momento, esse momento pode ser um formulário enviado via post ou via get, pode ser hard-code como fiz abaixo, você pode testar o funcionamento no site : http://phptester.net/

```
<?php 


// $valor = $_POST['valor']; 

// $valor = $_GET['valor']; 

$valor = 10; 

for ($i=1; $i <=$valor ; $i++) { 
            echo "
            <label>Chamado $i:</label><br>
            <input type='number' name='valor %i' placeholder='Chamado'>
            <br><br>
            ";

          }
```